# Apply css styling for page numbering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to apply one css style for number **2** using javascript. How can I do this using javascript from the following html.

```
<tfoot>
<tr class="pp-pagenumber">
    <td colspan="1">
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">&lt;</a>
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">1</a>
        2
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">3</a>
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">4</a>
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">&gt;</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

Finally it will look like the following image

[image]

As per Govan suggested i changed it to pure css. But now its looks like

[image]

Comment: Wrap the number of current page into a span element with attribute class or id and then you will be able to access it.

Comment: and what if you can't change HTML?

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript for this? You can do this in plain CSS.

Comment: @reporter its not possible to wrap it with span or anything, becuase its the format which is using by webgrid  control for paging

Comment: @stevenw00 Actually it is a webgrid control, you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286290/i-just-want-to-style-the-current-page-or-selected-page-in-a-webgrid-how-do-i-do in this i have mentioned the reason

Comment: In that case, maybe there is a setting in webgrid that can wrap "2" in a span?

Comment: @stevenw00 i searching for that for long, but did nt find any. we can add styling for 1 3 4 5 6 ... using webgrids footerStyle:"pp-pagenumber" property. but to apply style for 2 its hard

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript wrapping unwrapped plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183324/javascript-wrapping-unwrapped-plain-text)

Comment: I think this link gives some light to this problem

Comment: @kamienok your approach did the trick. Thanks. I think thats the only way to accomplish that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the number `2` you want to style is not within any tag its difficult to style that element. You can filter the nodes with type 3 which indicate for text nodes and wrap it in a tag with a specified class name. Then you can style that element with that class name

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tfoot>
<tr class="pp-pagenumber">
    <td colspan="1">
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">&lt;</a>
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">1</a>
        2
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">3</a>
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">4</a>
        <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">&gt;</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('tr.pp-pagenumber td').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).wrap('<a class="currentPage"></a>');


     /*You can remove the blank nodes if exists by */
    $(".currentPage").each(function(){
        if($(this).html().trim()=="")
            $(this).remove();
    });

});
</script>

<style>

.currentPage {

    background-color : green ; 
}

</style>
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <table>
 <tfoot>
 <tr class="pp-pagenumber">
  <td colspan="1">
   <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">&lt;</a>
   <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">1</a>
   2
   <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">3</a>
   <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">4</a>
   <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">&gt;</a> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tfoot>
 </table>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('tr.pp-pagenumber td').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).wrap('<a class="currentPage"></a>');
  
    $(".currentPage").each(function(){
   if($(this).html().trim()=="")
    $(this).remove();
  });


  
 });
 </script>

 <style>

 .currentPage {
  
  background-color : green ; 
 }

 </style>
```

Comment: Yes i was also following this approach after getting comment from kamienok. Any way this is the only way to accomplish this task, thanks it is working anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Pure CSS Fix:**

Try this and let me know it works or not.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs8e08L1/2/)

```
a::after {
    content: "*";
    background: white;
    color: white;
}

a::before {
    content: "*";
    background: white;
    color: white;
}

a {
    background: grey;
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

td {
    background: green;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Will check it in this way

Comment: @Govan Are you sure that the author can use JQuery?

Comment: @Goven is it possible for me to apply background color, width and height for $('td') ?

Comment: @Govan please see my edited question. Now its looks like this, after using pure css

Comment: Is there is any possibility to add extra span around 2 ?

Comment: Adjust margins as it fits.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need JS here?
Pure CSS should do the trick:

```
tr.pp-pagenumber td {color : red;}
tr.pp-pagenumber td a {color : black;}
```

Comment: the reason is its actually a Web grid control. you can find it here in my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286290/i-just-want-to-style-the-current-page-or-selected-page-in-a-webgrid-how-do-i-do its the paging format ehich used in webgrid control. And in my question you can see the style i am expecting to achieve

Comment: POZ after appying it now looks like, see my edited question

Comment: Ok, that is because you applied a background-color not just color. If you want a specific background for just the "2", you will need an element to wrap it such as a span.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on this:
[JavaScript wrapping unwrapped plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183324/javascript-wrapping-unwrapped-plain-text)

Maybe this could help you, there is solution how can you wrap this plain "2" with using JS.

Then you can style it like you need.

Answer (score 0):

add a onclick function to numbers and in onclick function just add a class to that button. write what ever css code you wnat to that class.

i think this will work for you.

```
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="pp-pagenumber">
        <td colspan="1">
            <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#" >&lt;</a>
            <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#" id="1" onclick="changeCss(this.id)">1</a>
            <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#" id="2" onclick="changeCss(this.id)">2</a>
            <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#" id="3" onclick="changeCss(this.id)">3</a>
            <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#" id="4" onclick="changeCss(this.id)">4</a>
            <a data-swhglnk="true" href="#">&gt;</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>

Java Script:
function changeCss(id){
   $(a).removeClass('changebutton');
   $("#"+id).addClass('changebutton');
}

css:
.changebutton{background-color:green;}
```

Comment: i cant wrap 2 inside anchor tag because its web grid control, and in web grid control the selected page number wont have anchor wrapping, and paging looks like the way in my qiestion

Comment: At that time the result looks like the second image in my question

Comment: to apply css to 2 you need to wrap it in any html tag otherwise we cant apply css styles.

Comment: Yes thats the issue i am facing, i cant remove this webgrid cotrnol, at the same time need to enable paging style.

Comment: then we need to follow the method as suggested by kamienok

Comment: yes i think that gives some light to this problem, i am checking in that way